# Variable of number. If condition not raising

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I would like to choose a range of number for change a image view color background.

I take the value of hz with my iPhone's microphone and this value is converter to string and the value is not fixed.
I would like to choose a number from 18000.000f to 1899.999f.

This is my code

```
if (maxHZ = 18000.000f) {
   Image.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
} else if(maxHZ >= 17999.999f ) {
    Image.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
} else if(maxHZ >= 18999.999f) {
    Image.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
```

Comment: `if (maxHZ == 18000.0f) { ...`, maybe... and your is statement makes zero sense, because the third branch will be invoked never as if the value is larger than `17999.999f` it _steals_ the fun from the third one – if the value would be smaller than `17999.999f` that must be smaller than `18999.999f`, so it won't be invoked ever.

Comment: On `if (maxHZ = 18000.000f)` you aren't checking whether `maxHZ` equals `18000.000f` you are assigning it to `maxHZ` change `=` to `==` note that there are two `=` for equality not one. If you just do one this is assigning.

Comment: @LucaTonelli, which one of explanations can cause difficulties to you?

Comment: sorry your comment is compare now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've corrected your code to right check, because you're using `else if`, it wont enter inside the last statement because if the last is true, the second is true too.

```
if (maxHZ == 18000.000f) {
   Image.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
} else if(maxHZ >= 17999.999f && maxHZ < 18999.999f ) {
    Image.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
} else if(maxHZ >= 18999.999f) {
    Image.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
```

As told in the comments, you should remove the first statement. It has 0.000000001% chance to enter inside.

```
if(maxHZ >= 18999.999f) {
    Image.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
} else {
    Image.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
```

or if he wants the black if it is not in that ether of those two ranges:

```
if(maxHZ >= 18999.999f) {
    Image.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
} else if(maxHZ >= 17999.999f) {
    Image.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
} else {
    Image.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Comment: might want to change the first case to (maxHZ <= 18000.000f) since its a float you will never see an exact match of 18000.000

Comment: No it's wrong, if he do that, it will enter in the first statement even if the value of maxHZ is 17999.999, but he don't want this.

Comment: What the point of the test `maxHZ >= 17999.999f`?

Comment: the black case will most likely never get called then

Comment: Agreed; this answer fixes the equality/assignment issues, but is still not perfect.

Comment: if you would have exchanged the last two `if` branches only, and you would not need the extra `maxHZ < 18999.999f` criteria...

Answer (score 1):

logically, I guess, something like this you may look for, I guess:

```
if (maxHZ >= 18999.999f) {
    Image.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
} else if (maxHZ == 18000.000f) {
    Image.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
} else if (maxHZ >= 17999.999f) {
    Image.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
} else {
    /* do something here, otherwise you would be left without explicit color */
}
```

---

*(personally I have no idea how many times you would see the black colour as the interval between `18000.0` and `17999.999` is a one thousandth, you input may have less accuracy to spot such insignificant difference.)*